# Windows/Linux issue with Client/Server Socket with Applet

Tags: java, applet, client-server

I'm new at socket programming and threads. I'd be happy if anyone can help me out.
I currently working on a multi-client server problem where each new client connection gets its own thread and its an applet. here is a code snippet of when to close the thread of a client when it disconnects.

```
   String inputMessage; //message stored here
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
   while((inputMessage = in.readLine()) != null){
            //Update message buffer with message that client has typed 
            buffer.insertMessage(inputMessage);

    }
    // Close things
        in.close();
        socket.close();
```

So when a null is read from the BufferedReader, it exits the while loop.
My issue is this works perfectly in linux. When x is pressed in the corner of the applet, the bufferedReader gets a null and the thread terminates gracefully.

When I tried this in windows, I get a SocketException:  Connection reset

```
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
```

Does windows and linux do something different when the applet is closed or is it my code

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Scanner` and check `hasNextLine()` before getting `nextLine()`

sample code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: No it won't. It will result in read() returning -1, readLine() retuning null, readXXX() throwing EOFException for any other XXX. Calling ready() won't solve this problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have written to an connection that had already been closed by the peer, or the peer has exited without closing the socket at all.